# Microsoft SQL Server API to run SQL queries to export data to a custom destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a few SQL queries to run in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018 to export data as `.txt` files. The `.txt` files are then imported to ElasticSearch via Logstash. At the moment, I'm running these queries manually via a many clicks operation:

1. Right click on the database
2. Click Tasks > Export Data
3. Choose my data source from SQL Server Native Client 11.0
4. Choose my destination as Flat File Destination.
5. Type my desired filename to store in the output folder.
6. Choose to Write a query to specify the data to transfer Copy and Paste my SQL Statement Finally a few next buttons and run it.

My question is, is there an API or a way to automatically run these queries periodically (once a day at 12 pm), and store it in a particular folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the Export defintion as an [SSIS package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/save-and-run-package-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017)

If you're running on your PC then you can run SSIS from a scheduled a task using [DTExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-cmdline?view=sql-server-2017)

If you're running it on the SQL server than you can configure a [SQL job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Note that dtexec will normally fail if you don't have SSIS installed.  With just SSMS you can't programmatically run SSIS packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:
SQLCMD command line SQL tool to send your query output to text file using -o switch. it can be scheduled using SQL Server Agent Job

Or you can use the SQL Job Step Advanced tab to specify an output file to receive the out from your job step.